# Why is XSLT only transforming first record?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using XSLT 1.0.  This is my 3d lifetime XSLT; I'm still learning.

**I have a single input XML document with multiple records.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<max:QueryNASAPERSONResponse xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:msg="http://types.msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/messages/v1/" xmlns:pers="http://types.msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/v1/" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                             xmlns:tns="http://msfc.nasa.gov/asset-query-service/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:typens="http://msfc.nasa.gov/asset-query-service/types/">
    <max:NASAPERSONSet>
        <max:PERSON>
            <max:DEPARTMENT>M-DI</max:DEPARTMENT>
            <max:DISPLAYNAME>AMY</max:DISPLAYNAME>
            <max:DROPPOINT>4201-117B-</max:DROPPOINT>
            <max:FIRSTNAME>AMY</max:FIRSTNAME>
            <max:LASTNAME>BANNISTER</max:LASTNAME>
            <max:LOCATION>4201-117B-</max:LOCATION>
            <max:OWNERSYSID>MIW</max:OWNERSYSID>
            <max:PERSONID>892949451</max:PERSONID>
            <max:PRIMARYEMAIL>AMY.BANNISTER@NASA.GOV</max:PRIMARYEMAIL>
            <max:PRIMARYPHONE>256-544-2331</max:PRIMARYPHONE>
            <max:SENDERSYSID>MIW</max:SENDERSYSID>
            <max:STATUS>ACTIVE</max:STATUS>
            <max:STATUSDATE>2015-06-25T00:00:00-05:00</max:STATUSDATE>
            <max:SUPERVISOR>KAREN VANSANT</max:SUPERVISOR>
            <max:TITLE>AUDITOR</max:TITLE>
            <max:NASAAUID>ABANNIST</max:NASAAUID>
        </max:PERSON>
        <max:PERSON>
            <max:DEPARTMENT>EV74</max:DEPARTMENT>
            <max:DISPLAYNAME>JACK</max:DISPLAYNAME>
            <max:DROPPOINT>OFFSITE--</max:DROPPOINT>
            <max:FIRSTNAME>JACK</max:FIRSTNAME>
            <max:LASTNAME>STOKES</max:LASTNAME>
            <max:LOCATION>OFFSITE--</max:LOCATION>
            <max:OWNERSYSID>MIW</max:OWNERSYSID>
            <max:PERSONID>426512344</max:PERSONID>
            <max:PRIMARYEMAIL>JACK.W.STOKES@NASA.GOV</max:PRIMARYEMAIL>
            <max:PRIMARYPHONE>256-544-1764</max:PRIMARYPHONE>
            <max:SENDERSYSID>MIW</max:SENDERSYSID>
            <max:STATUS>ACTIVE</max:STATUS>
            <max:STATUSDATE>2015-06-25T00:00:00-05:00</max:STATUSDATE>
            <max:SUPERVISOR>
            </max:SUPERVISOR>
            <max:TITLE>ENGINEER</max:TITLE>
            <max:NASAAUID>JSTOKES</max:NASAAUID>
        </max:PERSON>
        <max:PERSON>
            <max:DEPARTMENT>AS10</max:DEPARTMENT>
            <max:DISPLAYNAME>GREGORY</max:DISPLAYNAME>
            <max:DROPPOINT>4249-116D-</max:DROPPOINT>
            <max:FIRSTNAME>GREGORY</max:FIRSTNAME>
            <max:LASTNAME>SMITH</max:LASTNAME>
            <max:LOCATION>4249-116D-</max:LOCATION>
            <max:OWNERSYSID>MIW</max:OWNERSYSID>
            <max:PERSONID>264292430</max:PERSONID>
            <max:PRIMARYEMAIL>GREGORY.D.SMITH@NASA.GOV</max:PRIMARYEMAIL>
            <max:PRIMARYPHONE>256-544-5739</max:PRIMARYPHONE>
            <max:SENDERSYSID>MIW</max:SENDERSYSID>
            <max:STATUS>ACTIVE</max:STATUS>
            <max:STATUSDATE>2015-06-25T00:00:00-05:00</max:STATUSDATE>
            <max:SUPERVISOR>JAMES BANKS</max:SUPERVISOR>
            <max:TITLE>INDUSTRIAL HYGIENIST</max:TITLE>
            <max:NASAAUID>GDSMITH</max:NASAAUID>
        </max:PERSON>
        <max:PERSON>
            <max:DEPARTMENT>IS40</max:DEPARTMENT>
            <max:DISPLAYNAME>STEVE</max:DISPLAYNAME>
            <max:DROPPOINT>4485-114-4-</max:DROPPOINT>
            <max:FIRSTNAME>STEVE</max:FIRSTNAME>
            <max:LASTNAME>KNIGHT</max:LASTNAME>
            <max:LOCATION>4485-114-4-</max:LOCATION>
            <max:OWNERSYSID>MIW</max:OWNERSYSID>
            <max:PERSONID>922600141</max:PERSONID>
            <max:PRIMARYEMAIL>STEVE.E.KNIGHT@NASA.GOV</max:PRIMARYEMAIL>
            <max:PRIMARYPHONE>256-544-2999</max:PRIMARYPHONE>
            <max:SENDERSYSID>MIW</max:SENDERSYSID>
            <max:STATUS>ACTIVE</max:STATUS>
            <max:STATUSDATE>2015-06-25T00:00:00-05:00</max:STATUSDATE>
            <max:SUPERVISOR>RANDALL GOGGANS</max:SUPERVISOR>
            <max:TITLE>SYSTEM ANALYST</max:TITLE>
            <max:NASAAUID>SEKNIGHT</max:NASAAUID>
        </max:PERSON>
```

I have an XSLT to transform it, but it only transforms the first record from this XML.

**Here is the XSLT:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:mro="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
xmlns:msg="http://types.msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/messages/v1/" 
xmlns:pers="http://types.msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/v1/" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
xmlns:tns="http://msfc.nasa.gov/asset-query-service/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:typens="http://msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/types/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <InvokeNASAPERSONResponse xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <NASAPERSONSet>
                <PERSON>
                    <DEPARTMENT>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:DEPARTMENT"/>
                    </DEPARTMENT>
                    <DISPLAYNAME>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:DISPLAYNAME"/>
                    </DISPLAYNAME>
                    <DROPPOINT>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:DROPPOINT"/>
                    </DROPPOINT>
                    <FIRSTNAME>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:FIRSTNAME"/>
                    </FIRSTNAME>
                    <LASTNAME>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:LASTNAME"/>
                    </LASTNAME>
                    <LOCATION>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:LOCATION"/>
                    </LOCATION>
                    <OWNERSYSID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:OWNERSYSID"/>
                    </OWNERSYSID>
                    <PERSONID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:PERSONID"/>
                    </PERSONID>
                    <PRIMARYEMAIL>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:PRIMARYEMAIL"/>
                    </PRIMARYEMAIL>
                    <PRIMARYPHONE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:PRIMARYPHONE"/>
                    </PRIMARYPHONE>
                    <SENDERSYSID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:SENDERSYSID"/>
                    </SENDERSYSID>
                    <STATUS>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:STATUS"/>
                    </STATUS>
                    <STATUSDATE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:STATUSDATE"/>
                    </STATUSDATE>
                    <SUPERVISOR>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:SUPERVISOR"/>
                    </SUPERVISOR>
                    <TITLE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:TITLE"/>
                    </TITLE>
                    <PHONE>
                        <PHONENUM>
                            <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:PRIMARYPHONE"/>
                        </PHONENUM>
                        <ISPRIMARY>
                            <xsl:text>Y</xsl:text>
                        </ISPRIMARY>
                    </PHONE>
                    <EMAIL>
                        <EMAILADDRESS>
                            <xsl:value-of select="max:NASAPERSONSet/max:PERSON/max:PRIMARYEMAIL"/>
                        </EMAILADDRESS>
                    </EMAIL>
                </PERSON>               
            </NASAPERSONSet>
        </InvokeNASAPERSONResponse>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The output XML file I'm getting is:**

```
<InvokeNASAPERSONResponse xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:msg="http://types.msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/messages/v1/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:tns="http://msfc.nasa.gov/asset-query-service/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:pers="http://types.msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/v1/" xmlns:mro="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:typens="http://msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/types/">
  <NASAPERSONSet>
    <PERSON>
      <DEPARTMENT>M-DI</DEPARTMENT>
      <DISPLAYNAME>AMY</DISPLAYNAME>
      <DROPPOINT>4201-117B-</DROPPOINT>
      <FIRSTNAME>AMY</FIRSTNAME>
      <LASTNAME>BANNISTER</LASTNAME>
      <LOCATION>4201-117B-</LOCATION>
      <OWNERSYSID>MIW</OWNERSYSID>
      <PERSONID>892949451</PERSONID>
      <PRIMARYEMAIL>AMY.BANNISTER@NASA.GOV</PRIMARYEMAIL>
      <PRIMARYPHONE>256-544-2331</PRIMARYPHONE>
      <SENDERSYSID>MIW</SENDERSYSID>
      <STATUS>ACTIVE</STATUS>
      <STATUSDATE>2015-06-25T00:00:00-05:00</STATUSDATE>
      <SUPERVISOR>KAREN VANSANT</SUPERVISOR>
      <TITLE>AUDITOR</TITLE>
      <PHONE>
        <PHONENUM>256-544-2331</PHONENUM>
        <ISPRIMARY>Y</ISPRIMARY>
      </PHONE>
      <EMAIL>
        <EMAILADDRESS>AMY.BANNISTER@NASA.GOV</EMAILADDRESS>
      </EMAIL>
    </PERSON>
  </NASAPERSONSet>
</InvokeNASAPERSONResponse>
```

This is the only record in my output file.  How do I get it to loop through all the records in the XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template is only matching one element and outputting XML for it alone.  You want to either iterate (using `xsl:for-each`) or, better, recursively apply pattern matching (using `xsl:apply templates`).

Let's go with `xsl:apply-templates` as it's the preferred way to use XSLT's power elegantly...

**Use two templates:**

1. Similar to what you have, to match the greater
   `max:InvokeNASAPERSONResponse` and `max:NASAPERSONSet` context:

   ```
   <xsl:template match="max:QueryNASAPERSONResponse/max:NASAPERSONSet">
     <InvokeNASAPERSONResponse xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"
                             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <NASAPERSONSet>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </NASAPERSONSet>
     </InvokeNASAPERSONResponse>
   </xsl:template>
   ```
2. A new template to match each `max:PERSON`.

   ```
   <xsl:template match="max:PERSON">
     <InvokeNASAPERSONResponse xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"
                               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <!- ... -->
   ```

Notice how the two are tied together via `xsl:apply-templates`, which restarts the matching process with the children of `max:NASAPERSONSet`.

**Here they are altogether in your adjusted XSLT:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:mro="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
                xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
                xmlns:msg="http://types.msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/messages/v1/" 
                xmlns:pers="http://types.msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/v1/" 
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
                xmlns:tns="http://msfc.nasa.gov/asset-query-service/" 
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                xmlns:typens="http://msfc.nasa.gov/personnel/types/">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="max:QueryNASAPERSONResponse/max:NASAPERSONSet">
    <InvokeNASAPERSONResponse xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <NASAPERSONSet>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </NASAPERSONSet>
    </InvokeNASAPERSONResponse>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="max:PERSON">
    <InvokeNASAPERSONResponse xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <NASAPERSONSet>
        <PERSON>
          <DEPARTMENT>
            <xsl:value-of select="max:DEPARTMENT"/>
          </DEPARTMENT>
          <DISPLAYNAME>
            <xsl:value-of select="max:DISPLAYNAME"/>
          </DISPLAYNAME>
          <DROPPOINT>
            <xsl:value-of select="max:DROPPOINT"/>
          </DROPPOINT>
          <FIRSTNAME>
            <xsl:value-of select="max:FIRSTNAME"/>
          </FIRSTNAME>
          <LASTNAME>
            <xsl:value-of select="max:LASTNAME"/>
          </LASTNAME>
          <LOCATION>
            <xsl:value-of select="max:LOCATION"/>
          </LOCATION>
          <OWNERSYSID>
            <xsl:value-of select="max:OWNERSYSID"/>
          </OWNERSYSID>
          <PERSONID>
            <xsl:value-of select="max:PERSONID"/>
          </PERSONID>
          <PRIMARYEMAIL>
            <xsl:value-of select="max:PRIMARYEMAIL"/>
          </PRIMARYEMAIL>
          <PRIMARYPHONE>
            <xsl:value-of select="max:PRIMARYPHONE"/>
          </PRIMARYPHONE>
          <SENDERSYSID>
            <xsl:value-of select="max:SENDERSYSID"/>
          </SENDERSYSID>
          <STATUS>
            <xsl:value-of select="max:STATUS"/>
          </STATUS>
          <STATUSDATE>
            <xsl:value-of select="max:STATUSDATE"/>
          </STATUSDATE>
          <SUPERVISOR>
            <xsl:value-of select="max:SUPERVISOR"/>
          </SUPERVISOR>
          <TITLE>
            <xsl:value-of select="max:TITLE"/>
          </TITLE>
          <PHONE>
            <PHONENUM>
              <xsl:value-of select="max:PRIMARYPHONE"/>
            </PHONENUM>
            <ISPRIMARY>
              <xsl:text>Y</xsl:text>
            </ISPRIMARY>
          </PHONE>
          <EMAIL>
            <EMAILADDRESS>
              <xsl:value-of select="max:PRIMARYEMAIL"/>
            </EMAILADDRESS>
          </EMAIL>
        </PERSON>               
      </NASAPERSONSet>
    </InvokeNASAPERSONResponse>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```